# Tamron 18-200 mm vs Nikkor 18-200 mm lens

Tags: nikon, tamron

After going through both lens specification i got really confused about the pricing of Nikkor lens

Following are detail i noticed

```
                   |Nikkor 18-200  | Tamron 18-200
 1 Lens Elements   |     16        |       15 
 2 Lens Groups     |     12        |       13
 3 Diaphragm Blades|      7        |        7
 4 Angle of view   |     76-8      |       75-8
 5 Min Focus Dist  |    0.5m       |      0.45mm
 6 Price           |   $596.95     |     $199.00
```

Please guide me why Nikkor is so highly priced

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I'll suggest that that minimum focus distance for the Nikon is actually smaller in practice. The stated value is conservative. It practically focuses like a macro lens.

Answer (score 3):

### VR

The Nikkon 18-200 has VR, the Tamron 18-200 does not. VR can give you an advantage worth two or three stops on the aperture. Nikon claim [up to four stops](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Article/ftlzi4s6/vibration-reduction.html)

There are some relatively cheap Nikon lenses that include VR. For example

- [18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-S VR DX NIKKOR](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/nikon_18-55_3p5-5p6_vr_n15)  [$197](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/532521-GREY/Nikon_2176_18_55mm_f_3_5_5_6G_VR_AF_S.html)
- [55-200mm f/4-5.6G AF-S DX Nikkor VR](http://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/lenses/nikon_55-200_4-5p6_vrdx) - [$247](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/486717-GREY/Nikon_2166_AF_S_DX_VR_Zoom_Nikkor.html)
- [18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-S DX Nikkor ED VR II](http://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/lenses/nikon_18-200_3p5-5p6_vr_afs) - [$597](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/644744-USA/Nikon_2192_AF_S_DX_NIKKOR_18_200mm.html)

Tamron have a [18-200 VC](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/18200_diIII_B011.php#ad-image-0) lens for CSC cameras (not Nikon F-mount) which is [more expensive](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1060227-REG/tamron_afb011em_700_18_200mm_f_3_5_6_3_di_iii.html) than, for example, their [18-200 XR](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/18200_diII.php) (which also lacks an in-lens AF motor)

### ED

The Nikkor has [ED glass](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-solutions/why-ed-ld-eld-sld-and-asph-glass-make-difference-your-photographs) in some elements and some aspheric elements. This should reduce chromatic aberration. I think the Tamron XR has some aspheric elements and [LR and XD elements](http://www.lenstip.com/280.3-Lens_review-Tamron_AF_18-200_mm_f_3.5-6.3_XR_Di-II_LD_Aspherical_(IF)_Build_quality.html). You'd have to look into this in more detail or otherwise form your own opinion regarding chromatic aberration in images from both lenses.

### Name

There probably is a premium for a good brand name but probably not enough to account for all the difference in price.

---

See also

- [What are ED elements?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23072/2520)
- [How does a spherical lens differ from an aspherical lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10823/2520)
- [Why ED, LD, ELD, SLD and ASPH Glass Make a Difference](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-solutions/why-ed-ld-eld-sld-and-asph-glass-make-difference-your-photographs)
- [Tamron vs Nikon 18-200](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/41790631)
- [Best superzoom for Nikon DSLRs: 8 tested](http://beta.techradar.com/news/photography-video-capture/cameras/best-superzoom-for-nikon-dslrs-8-tested-1066305/2)

Comment: There are a few problems with your answer here, mostly because the OP is comparing two lenses from different ranges. The cheapest Tamrons may not have VR but neither do the Nikons, in this cases the cheaper Nikon 18-200 4.5+ does but it won't give you anywhere near an extra 3 stops. You have made an assumption of build quality differences, is this a fact or just "probably"?

Comment: @connersz: I wrote *"There are **probably** numerous other differences in materials and build quality"* - but I agree it doesn't help the OP (who should go to a shop and handle both) so I've removed that remark. Some refs added for other points.

Answer (score 2):

Your example above presumes that there are only 5 possible variables between to two lenses which could contribute towards the price.

The fact is that there are many other reasons why the price could be higher:

- Build Quality
- Lens Coatings
- Perceived image quality
- Maximum aperture
- Aperture blade type

I won't go on, because there are just too many. I would also expect the Nikon lens to be slightly more expensive anyway, even if every possible comparable element is equal but that is purely my opinion.

If you are simply looking to compare those few properties, then I would say go with the Tamron as it would clearly be a very good deal.

Comment: build quality is a big issue here. Nikon builds lenses that hold up to rougher handling than Tamron, which uses a lot more plastic and so can't handle the bumps and bruises of heavy usage as well. A list of stats rarely tells the entire story...

Comment: @chuqui Not on all lenses they don't. Just like Tamron Nikon have a set of lenses with better build quality and a higher price point to go with them.

Comment: true, thanks for pointing that out, but my experience and from talking to others is they still aren't up to a Nikon build quality, FWIW.

Comment: @chuqui Well they may or may not be, but what matters is what's important to you. I know people that use the cheapest lenses all the time and never have an issue. The chances are you're not going to be that rough with a lens that costs 3 x more anyway. My cheapest lens cost £80/$100 and it's still going just fine.